# Why do the values in this change when I use emits and when I do not use emits in Vue3?

Tags: vuejs3, nuxt3

why do the values in this change when I use emits and when I do not use emits?

I am using the Options API in my Nuxt3 ("nuxt":"^3.5.2",) project.

I am wondering about the following: why do the values in this change when I use emits and when I do not use emits?

with emits

```
  emits: ['change'], // add
  computed: {
    text: {
      get: function() {
        console.log("here:", this.value)
        return this.value
      },
      set: function(value) {
        this.$emit("change", value)
      },
    },
  },
```

result
=> "string"

without emits

```
  // emits: ['change'], // remove
  computed: {
    text: {
      get: function() {
        console.log("here:", this.value)
        return this.value
      },
      set: function(value) {
        this.$emit("change", value)
      },
    },
  },
```

result
=> Event Object
warnings: [Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "value". Expected String with value "[object Event]", got Event

am curious as to why emits affect the value.

Answer (score 0):

check what kind of value the computed variable text is getting. May String is the emit default payload and you have to set if other type